# Change input value to a JSON value

Tags: json

I am looking to change the original text input value to a JSON value.

This randoms one of the similar artists that is searched. But I need that value to replace the input value whenever I hit the button to search.

So for example if I search Metallica, the code below would randomly pick 1 similar artist and then I want that to replace Metallica search originally set.

```
<input id="artists" type="text"</input>
<button id="searchy">Search Now</button>

function newartist(artist) {
    var url = 'http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/similar';
    var args = {
        format:'json', 
        api_key : apikey,
        name: artist,
        results : 5,
    };

    $.getJSON(url, args,
            function(data) {
                    var artist = data.response.artists[Math.floor(Math.random()*data.response.artists.length)];
                    console.log(artist.name);
            }
        );
}

function start() {
    var artist = $.trim($("#artists").val()); 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#searchy").click(start);
});
```

Is there a way to replace the original input value to my new JSON value?

Any help would be grateful, Thanks.

Comment: There's no JSON here. JSON is only being used behind the scenes. By the time your code is dealing with it, it's a JavaScript object, not JSON text (and JSON is always text, like HTML).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to search on Metallica (for example), then randomly pick an artist from the results, and search again. I presume you don't want to keep looping.

If so, just call `newartist` from your success callback, with a flag saying not to do it again:

```
function newartist(artist, dontRepeat) {
    var url = 'http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/similar';
    var args = {
        format:'json', 
        api_key : apikey,
        name: artist,
        results : 5,
    };

    $.getJSON(url, args,
            function(data) {
                    var artist;

                    if (dontRepeat || data.response.artists.length === 0) {
                        // ...do something useful with the results
                    } else {
                        // Do the second search
                        artist = data.response.artists[Math.floor(Math.random()*data.response.artists.length)];
                        newartist(artist.name, true);
                    }
            }
        );
}
```